# Как сделать кнопки вместо radio переключателя CSS

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как стилизовать радио переключатели под кнопки? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/button/#radio

Comment: Есть вот такой вариант [Css radio переключатель](http://webkaa.ru/css/radio_css)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Примерно так. Дальше стилизуйте сами `label`, как угодно вам.

```css
label {
  width: 100px; height: 50px; background: tomato;
  display: inline-block;
}
input {
/*   display: none */
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="one" name='radio'/>
<input type="radio" id="two" name='radio'/>
<br />
<label for="one">one</label>
<label for="two">two</label>
```