# В место обычных radio сделать красивые кнопки

Tags: html, css

Необходимо, чтобы переключатели `radio` были в виде кнопки с текстом внутри.

Подскажите как изменить обычные `radio` кружки в нормальные кнопки ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: ни 1 точки, ни 1 запятой ... когда спрашиваете нужно хоть немного соблюдать правила русского языка, думая о тех кому потом придется читать Ваш вопрос.

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать кнопки вместо radio переключателя CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515269/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-radio-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-css)

Answer (score 1):

Уверен, ты ищешь это:

ссылка: [ссылка на оригинал](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/css-radio-button-checkbox-background/)

```css
body {
  font-family: calibri;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio]+label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -2px;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  background-image: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
Click radio buttons to select: <br/><br/>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios">
<label for="radio2">Обычный покупатель</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios">
<label for="radio3">Оптовый покупатель</label>
<br><br>
```

Comment: для меня это не понятнотак как тут не идет как на чистой странице все
тут куча всего разного обьявлено и что куда вставить

Comment: как я понял, тебя интересует первый вариант кнопок, @StoWatt нажми после всех кодов, которые я вставил "выполнить код " и посмотри. Meanwhile, я изменю свой ответ

Comment: @StoWatt посмотри на код теперь

Comment: я не могу найти все переменные
нашел
input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
не могу найти эти
input[type=radio] + label, input[type=checkbox] + label {
input[type=radio]:checked + label, input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{

Comment: необязательно писать в ответе, что ответ обновлен. это видно по дате последнего изменения под вопросом. Также, если не ошибаемся, после правки Вами ответа, автор вопроса и все кто голосовал по вашему ответу получают уведомления.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hghehd
вот что я нашел,
помогите пожалуйста,
не могу ничего найти по поводу радио плюс лэйбл
одни или радио или лэйбл

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hghibl вот что получилось добиться
не могу найти cheked

Comment: помогите разобраться куда вставлять
а то у меня другие тут переменные и некоторых нету

Comment: не понимаю ничего ,
там все по другому,
в стилях нету никаких переменных,
где искать , куда копать

Comment: @Alex помогите объяснить, что автор имеет ввиду. Я не знаю, как помочь ему...

Comment: @Alex  В описании вопроса я вложил ссылку на сайт,
зайдите, нажмите F12, и по пробуйте найти все строки куда надо записывать стили и вы убедитесь что их там не найти и никак не отредактировать, вот я и не понимаю что и куда вводить, куда все переменные писать если я и так их найти не могу

Comment: @StoWatt Вам нужно не искать данный код на своем сайте, а  **добавить** стили из данного ответа в Ваш файл стилей, а также привести html код кнопок к виду, указанному в данном ответе. Следует понимать, что код в ответе есть пример того как можно сделать, внедрять код на свой сайт Вам нужно самостоятельно.

Comment: @Alex спасибо вам за помощь)

Comment: Да, код надо самому вставлять. т.к. как у меня нет прав доступа к вашему (@StoWatt) ресурсу